# Deep zoom image creation throws exception in c#

Tags: c#, deepzoom

Iam building a website which uses a pivot viewer that uses a deep zoom collection to show images and the metadata from a database. Iam using the deezoomtools.dll from microsoft to create the deep zoom collection.

From this website i can start a thread that starts the creation of several collection. For small collections this process goes just fine, however when doing a large collection it fails regularly.

I added some debug lines to see what happens and the exception i get is:
Thread was aborted as the message and as stack trace where it came from.

I found that when the images are processed the exception occurs. I guess that the error occurs in this code sample in the function *GetImageForDeepZoomComposer*

```
 private bool processImage(Item collectionItem, string backupImage,StreamWriter _logFile)
    {
        try
        {
            _logFile.WriteLine("start process");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(collectionItem.Image))
                return false;
            if (!File.Exists(collectionItem.ImagePath))
                return false;
            _logFile.WriteLine("File is there");
            if (!AllImagesUnique) // check to see if we have processed this exact file before.
                if (cacheOfImageIds.ContainsKey(collectionItem.ImagePath)) // we already have have processed this image so don't do it again
                {
                    collectionItem.ImageId = cacheOfImageIds[collectionItem.ImagePath];
                    return true;
                }

            _logFile.WriteLine("Get Image: " + collectionItem.ImagePath);
            string workingImage = GetImageForDeepZoomComposer(collectionItem.ImagePath, collectionItem.Id);
            _logFile.WriteLine("Image aquired");

            _logFile.WriteLine("collection name and id");
            string deepZoomImage = DeepZoomImageDir + collectionItem.Id;

            sendAction(string.Format("\tConverting image {0} to Deep Zoom Output file {1} ", workingImage,
                                             deepZoomImage));
            //imageCreator.Create(workingImage, deepZoomImage);
            _logFile.WriteLine("set image surrogate");
            SurrogateImageInfo sii = new SurrogateImageInfo(workingImage, "DeepZoomImages/" + Path.GetFileName(deepZoomImage) + ".xml");
            _logFile.WriteLine("image surrogate set");
            images.Add(sii);
            if (!AllImagesUnique) // if we want to make sure we don't use the Deep Zoom Composer on the same file twice then add this image to the cache
                cacheOfImageIds.Add(collectionItem.ImagePath, collectionItem.Id);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logFile.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            sendAction(
                string.Format(
                    "\tSkipping current item cause of execption encountered while processing the image\r\n\t\t{0}",
                    ex.Message));                             
            return false; // this item will not be added to the collection
        }
    }

 internal string GetImageForDeepZoomComposer(string imageFile,int id)
    {
        if (imageFile.StartsWith("http://") || imageFile.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            if (_client == null) // if we havent used the WebClient for this collection yet create one
                _client = new WebClient();

            string tempFile = ImageDownloadDir + Guid.NewGuid();
            sendAction(string.Format("\tDownloading image '{0} to {1}", imageFile, tempFile));
            _client.DownloadFile(imageFile, tempFile);
            return tempFile;
        }
        else if (imageFile.StartsWith("\\") || imageFile.StartsWith("E:\\") || imageFile.StartsWith("e:\\"))
        {

            var dir = Path.Combine(DeepZoomImageDir, id.ToString() + "_files");
            //if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            //    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            var fixedSizeFileName = imageFile.Replace("_thumb", "_fs");
            //create a fixed size image if it's not already created
            if (!File.Exists(fixedSizeFileName))
                FixedSize(new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageFile), 512, 512).Save(fixedSizeFileName,codecInfo,parameters);
            //copy the fixed size image to the DeepZoomImages folder so it can be used when zooming in to the deepest level
            var localFixedSizeImage = Path.Combine(DeepZoomImageDir, id + ".jpg");
            File.Copy(fixedSizeFileName, localFixedSizeImage);
            return localFixedSizeImage;
        }
        return imageFile;
    }
```

I think it has something to do with images that are locked when it tries to get the image and tries to save it with a different name such that it could be used. Iam truly at a loss here.

Thank you in advance for the information

Comment: The exception i always get is: thread was aborted

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but just in case you can't get deepZoomTools to work, there are other options: http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/creating-zooming-images/